# Can running git-bash raise security concerns?

Tags: windows, security, git-bash

Executing [the portable git for 64-bit Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.37.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.37.1-64-bit.7z.exe) from https://git-scm.com/download/win  caused a  cybersecurity alarm in a company. Why could it happen?
Can running the file indeed raise security concerns?

Answer (score 1):

It can happen depending on the structure of the archive (an auto-extracting exe)

But executing it is one option.
Another way to "install" it is to use a uncompress tool, like [Peazip](https://peazip.github.io/), which includes [7zip](https://peazip.github.io/7zip-files-utility.html), and can  uncompress pretty much anything.

Make a `pzxx.bat` in a folder which is referenced by your `%PATH%` (type `set PATH` to see its value, and choose a folder)

```bash
@echo off
set "sz=C:\Program Files\PeaZip\res\7z\7z.exe"
rem https://superuser.com/questions/194659/how-to-disable-the-output-of-7-zip
for /F %%i in ("%1") do "%sz%" x -aos -pdefault -sccUTF-8 "%%i" -o%%~ni -bso0 -bsp1
```

From there, go to the folder where you have the [`PortableGit-2.37.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.37.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.37.1-64-bit.7z.exe) file and type:

```
pzxx PortableGit-2.37.1-64-bit.7z.exe
```

You will get a folder name `PortableGit-2.37.1-64-bit.7z` in which you will have the latest 2.37.1 Git ready to use.

Type `mklink /J current PortableGit-2.37.1-64-bit.7z` and add to your `%PATH%`:

```
set "GH=%C:\path\to\Git\current"
set "PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%"
```

Since `GH` reference a junction folder "`current`", the `PATH` to Git will never change. All you need to do for the next Git is:

```bash
cd C:\Path\to\Git
pzxx PortableGit-2.38.0-64-bit.7z.exe
rmdir current
mklink /J current PortableGit-2.38.0-64-bit.7z
```

The `%PATH%` won't need to change.

Comment: Thanks. Is it the extraction done by running executable PortableGit-2.37.1-64-bit.7z.exe which raised the alarm? Not running git-bash in the extracted files? Why is that dangerous?

Comment: @Tim The auto-extracted exe did trigger the anti-virus. But uncompressing it through 7Zip should not. Nothing to do with git bash though

Comment: @Tim I suspect because it was so recently release its signature wasn't fully analyzed/validated yet. This should resolve itself in the next few days.

Comment: Are self-extracting executable files monitored differently from other executables (like git bash itself) by cybersecurity departments?

Comment: @Tim No, this is more about the fact it is a recent file, not yet fully vetted by AV.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , allowing a service that uses a more than 5 ports to send / receove is definitely a security threat.